Action Filter & Attributes
I am trying to set up action filter with attribute in ASP.NET Web api.
Here is the filter
public class PermissionRequirementFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly string[] _permissions;

    public PermissionRequirementFilter(string[] permissions)
    {
        _permissions = permissions;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var claim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;
        var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IntegrationContext>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var roleClaim = claim.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "extension_Role");
        //TODO Rest of logic here
}

Here is the attribute
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class RequiredPermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RequiredPermissionAttribute(string[] permissions) : base(typeof(PermissionRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = // Not sure what to do here...
    }
}

Here is how i would like to use this in the controller.
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class AbcController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [RequiredPermission(new []{"permission_1", "permission_2"})]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok("test");
    }
}

I have tried variations of this but i can never seem to get the code to hit the filter without registering it (cant use the data from attribute then)
Anyone have any ideas?

Consider using policy-based authorization for this kind of stuff instead. You could define your own MyRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement, define an AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement> which can check that reqirement, then add a policy with that requierment and finally check for that policy using the [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicyWhichChecksAuhorizationRequirement")] attribute.

@Mushroomator, upon investigation i dont think this is what we need. i need to specify a list of permissions e.g delete_item, get_item, update_item then i need to do a check in db to see if the userid claim has access to these permissions... what do you think

This is the best way i have found
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class RequiredPermissionAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string[] Permissions { get; }

    public RequiredPermissionAttribute(params string[] permissions)
    {
        Permissions = permissions;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var claim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;
        var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IntegrationContext>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
       //TODO
    }
}

In the controller
[HttpGet]
[RequiredPermission("Permission1", "Permission2")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok("test");
}

